# Directive that include page where TemplateUrl is created from an attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have meta application written in Angular.js and I can create apps using Angular but with some limitations. I can use and create directives and create page that are automaticaly added to $route.

I need directive `widget` that will use other page as template but the page url need to be dynamic (based on attribute) `<widget name="page"/>` will include template using `name` attribute, here is my code:

```
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
        this.templateUrl = $route.routes['/<APP-NAME>/' + tAttrs.name].templateUrl;
    }
};
```

I was thinking that maybe I can use $http to fetch the template, but can I return promise from compile function and how to replace the template?

Comment: You really should have mentioned that you use angular 1.06, since very much has changed since then.

Comment: @zeroflagL I've try your code in version 1.2.x and it work, you should undelete the answer I'll accept it. Too bad I can use with the system I'm force to use.

Comment: That's kind of you. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`templateUrl` can be a function. So you can write something like

```
function getUrl(tElement, tAttrs) {
  return tAttrs.name;
}

return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  replace: true,
  templateUrl: getUrl
};
```

Angular gets the template itself.